# Adding a different last page in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# 2010 application that contains a report created using Crystal Reports for VS2010. Its purpose is printing an invoice for a client. I need to add a page (same for each invoice) that shows the methods by which the client can pay the invoice.

This would basically require me to add a page that is different from the rest of the report, at the end of the report. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember 100% if the Crystal for VS2010 supports it but Crystal Reports does have the option for defining a report footer section.  If you activate this section and configure page break before to be on this should have the effect you desire.

*Addition by Vlad Schnakovszki:*

To prevent the Page Header section from appearing on the last page, do this:

Right-click on the Footer Section, choose Format Section. Click the button beside the Suppress (No Drill-Down) under Common Tab and place this code.

```
if pagenumber=TotalPageCount then true
else false
```

*Bob Vale* - Alternatively just put the formula as `pagenumber=TotalPageCount`

Source [here](http://www.dbforums.com/crystal-reports/1212970-how-suppress-page-header-footer-last-page.html).

Comment: That works but the Page Header appears on the last page as well. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You will need to assign a suppress function to the page header section, possibly something along the lines of `PageNumber = TotalPageCount`